# Stumped on why my function only prints one value

Tags: python

Working on a function that takes 4 values, rounds two, and prints a status of them.

```
def show_status(altitude,speed,fuel,strength):

    '''  
    consumes altitude, speed, fuel, strength, prints lander's status  
    Parameters:  
        altitude (float)  
        speed (float)  
        fuel (int)  
        strength (int)  
    return:  
        statusalt (float)  
        statusspeed (float)  
        statusfuel (int)  
        statusstrength (int)  
    '''  
    statusalt=float(altitude)  
    statusspeed = float(speed)  
    statusfuel = int(fuel)  
    statusstrength = int(strength)  
    return statusalt  
    return statusspeed  
    return statusfuel  
    return statusstrength  
    print ("Alt = ",statusalt," Vel = ",statusspeed," Fuel = ",statusfuel," Str = ",statusstrength) 

show_status(12,34,56,78)
```

gives

```
12.0
```

I've been working on this for a few hours. No idea what I'm doing wrong. It's just printing the value of altitude.

Comment: you have 4 returns that's why.

Comment: If my indentation fix with your code is wrong, please correct it. Otherwise I'll assume this is what your code was meant to look like.

Comment: AH! Thanks everyone! I'm in intro to comp sci, and for whatever reason, I thought I could return more than one value, and just print it like how it was. Thanks again.

Comment: You can have multiple returning values from a function, that's called an iterator. You create this by replacing all the `return ...` with `yield ....` instead. But it will also give you another end result. Where you would call the function by `list(show_status(12, 34, 56, 78))` instead or iterate over your function call. You can try it by doing `print(list(show_status(12, 34, 56, 78)))`. Just a penny for your thought.

Answer (score 1):

It's because after the first `return` statement, the rest of the function will not be executed. If you want to return this properly to use it in a string you should return it as a tuple:

```
return (statusalt, statusspeed, statusfuel, statusstrength)
```

and then you can write:

```
print ("Alt = %d Vel = %d Fuel = %d Str = %d" %(show_status(12,34,56,78)))
```

Answer (score 0):

when a function arrives a return command, it return the value and exits the function.
if you want to return some values, you must do it in one line

```
return statusalt, statusspeed, statusfuel, statusstrength
```

this will return a tuple

Answer (score 0):

You should make the function return the four statuses as a tuple, and make the caller unpack the tuple into 4 variables and print them instead:

```
def show_status(altitude,speed,fuel,strength):
    '''
    consumes altitude, speed, fuel, strength, prints lander's status
    Parameters:
        altitude (float)
        speed (float)
        fuel (int)
        strength (int)
    return:
        statusalt (float)
        statusspeed (float)
        statusfuel (int)
        statusstrength (int)
    '''
    statusalt=float(altitude)
    statusspeed = float(speed)
    statusfuel = int(fuel)
    statusstrength = int(strength)
    return statusalt, statusspeed, statusfuel, statusstrength
statusalt, statusspeed, statusfuel, statusstrength = show_status(12,34,56,78)
print ("Alt = ",statusalt," Vel = ",statusspeed," Fuel = ",statusfuel," Str = ",statusstrength)
```